# Flexbox scrollbar issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm getting a mysterious and undesirable scrollbar.  I made a pen to reproduce the issue.  I found several culprits that fix the problem, and I've identified them in the CSS comments.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?  Or is it just me that's seeing this?  Given that a small variation in font-family or font-size fix the problem, I'm guessing its a bug.

(I'm on Windows 10, Chrome 55 and Firefox 51)

**Update:** Michael_B (Win 10, Chrome 55) cannot reproduce the issue.  If you, like me, see a scrollbar when viewing the pen, could you please report so in comments?  Thanks.

http://codepen.io/technolojesus/pen/EZEBqW

Here's the code:

```
<div id="app">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;

  /* normalize.css does this.. 
  strangely, removing this line-height property fixes the problem */
  line-height: 1.15;

  /*
    default font:  no scrollbar
    Verdana: scrollbar
    Tahoma: no scrollbar
    "Open Sans": scrollbar
  */
  font-family: Verdana;

    /*
    font-size: 11px --> no scrollbar
    font-size: 12px --> scrollbar
    font-size: 13px --> scrollbar
    font-size: 14px --> no scrollbar
  */
  font-size: 12px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#app {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  /* strangely, adding padding here makes the scrollbar disappear */

  /* padding: 1px; */
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here in Chrome 55, Windows 10. Never any scrollbar.

Comment: Great... thanks for trying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an issue they not yet found at `normalize css`, resetting the line-height to 1.15, when used with `flexbox` (might be in other situations as well)

As most browsers defaults to a line height of ~ 1.2, and if you set that, everything works well on all browsers, but as soon as you go below, Firefox create scrollbar at 1.15, Chrome and Edge at 1.1.

When you set these lower values (less than 1.2) one can clearly see the text overflows its container, especially when letters like `g` is used, but the calculated height is the height of the container, hence scroll appears.

So by removing the line-height (or give it a higher value), or add padding, or anything that creates a height in the header/footer, will solve the overflow issue.

*I am quite sure there is a technical clarification to be found at W3C, though I don't know where to find it, so if any one does, feel free to add a link in my answer, or post an answer of your own*

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 flex children: `header`, `main` and `footer`. But you've given a flex value only to the main section. In simple terms you aren't telling the browser what to do with header and footer so it's pushing them out.

To fix, give your header and footer a measurement. Anything, even something as simple as the following:

```
header, footer {
    background: #ddd;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Yea, but that's not the problem.  I think it's my system, and/or a strange bug

Comment: To clarify - the layout defined in the pen *should* work w/ or w/o a height.  Giving it a height (among the other things I mentioned) seems to mask the problem - but until I find the underlying reason behind it, I don't want it to mysteriously reappear, yanno?

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: The layout is supposed to grow to fit the viewport, regardless of the height of the footer.  Changing the height, font-size, line-height, etc shouldn't make a difference.  The fact that it does make a difference indicates that there's a bug with the calculation, that only shows up in certain instances.